# Autoplot function and decomposition

Tags: r, ggplot2, forecast

I am using the forecast package and I tried to make a decomposition plot. Below you can see the code.

```
library(forecast)
librarary(ggplot2)
stl(AirPassengers,s.window="periodic",robust=TRUE)%>%autoplot()
```

These lines of code produce a plot with four charts below you can see the plot

[image]

Now I want to have this plot but without the first chart (data). So can anybody help me how to solve this problem and make a plot only with three charts (trend, seasonal, and remainder )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to manually manipulate the `ggplot2` object returned by `autoplot`, e.g. to get rid of the `data` panel you could remove the `data` values from the plot data and the layer data.

As the categories for the facets are stored in a column called `parts` we have to filter the data to get rid of the `parts` category `"data"`:

```r
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)

p <- stl(AirPassengers,s.window="periodic",robust=TRUE) |> autoplot()

# Remove "data" from layer data
p$layers <- lapply(p$layers, function(x) { x$data <- subset(x$data, parts != "data"); x })
# Remove "data" from plot data
p$data <- subset(p$data, parts != "data")

p
```

[image]